# Open-Source Investment "Management" Portfolio Tracker (Linux Desktop)

Tags: open-source, finance, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Are there any open-source Portfolio Tracker software for the Linux Desktop?

I'm looking into doing foreign exchange trading (forex). More specifically, I'd like to trade cryptocurrency pairs like Bitcoin and Monero (XMR-BTC)

- https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XMR-BTC/

Unfortunately, as I'm just simulating orders, I'm fiding that [a] it's very complex to stay on-top of my profit/loss over time when trading with different quantites back-and-forth and [b] GNU Cash just isn't quite up to this task, due to lack of precision

- https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152962/gnu-cash-stocks-using-smaller-than-0-01-in-buy-and-sell-transaction-column

What I *am* looking for:

1. Something where I manually type in all my investment transactions (eg `last week I bought 0.342465753 XMR and I paid with 0.0025 BTC` and `today I sold 0.3 XMR and got 0.0023946 BTC`)
2. Something that can track the value of all my assets in cryptocurrency (ie I don't care the value in dollars or euros. I just want to see my net worth calculated in Bitcoins).
3. Something that will give me fancy reports (eg yearly/monthly/weekly profit/loss reports, tell me my average overall buy-in for each currency, etc)

What I'm *not* looking for:

1. Something that queries my bank accounts and injests data for me
2. An app where I purchase actual investments (eg stocks) inside the app itself
3. A mobile app
4. A cloud-based web app

Comment: See also https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Tools_and_calculators#Portfolio_tools

Comment: I'm currently using a spreadsheet. For info on the information I'm tracking and how to calculate them, see https://money.stackexchange.com/a/153009/119380

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, I suggest you look at:

- [Portfolio Performance](https://www.portfolio-performance.info/en/)
- [Cryptofolio](https://github.com/Xtrendence/Cryptofolio)
- [Ghostfolio](https://github.com/ghostfolio/ghostfolio)

They can run on Linux, can be used for recording buy/sell transactions, calculating returns, reports, etc. I can't recall if all can do pairs without the individual legs. But you can confirm by checking the manuals/issues logs.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find out how to add a currency. It converts everything back to fiat :(

Comment: Which one of the three did you check? Cryptofolio is more for cryptos though.

Comment: I tried Portfolio Performance. I'm not really looking for a big web application. I just want a simple program without dependencies on a separate DB app, etc

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're asking for, but you're going to have the best flexibility if you use a spreadsheet. Consider LibreOffice.

To help you figure-out the calculations, checkout [CoinTracking.info](https://cointracking.info/documentation.php).

It's a cloud-based webapp, but the documentation is great. Just throw some artificial numbers in it, and expand the calculations sections by expanding `[click here for the detailed calculation]`. Then replicate that in your spreadsheet.

Or use their service directly. It's free.