# On-Prem Securities Investment Tracking of "tax lots" (accounting, stocks, LIFO, bitcoin)

Tags: open-source, finance

Are there any programs for Linux Desktop that can track purchases of securities and/or cryptocurrencies and group them into lots?

I want to track purchases and sales of securities using "tax lots". Specifically, I want to use the "Lowest In, First Out" to group "sell" orders with "buy" orders in the lots.

> Note: I'm looking to use this program for performance tracking of profit/loss, not for tax purposes

Currently I'm just using LibreOffice to track my transactions, but it's extremely difficult to group transactions into lots when the quantities of shares purchased differ. It's possible, but it's a lot row-specific formula inputs that are likely to lead to calculation errors.

What I *am* looking for:

1. Something where I manually type in all my investment transactions (eg `last week I bought 0.342465753 XMR and I paid with 0.0025 BTC` and `today I sold 0.3 XMR and got 0.0023946 BTC`)
2. Something that can track the value of all my assets in cryptocurrency (ie I don't care the value in dollars or euros. I just want to see my net worth calculated in Bitcoins).
3. Something that will give me fancy reports (eg yearly/monthly/weekly profit/loss reports, tell me my average overall buy-in for each currency, etc)

What I'm *not* looking for:

1. Something that queries my bank accounts and injests data for me
2. An app where I purchase actual investments (eg stocks) inside the app itself
3. A mobile app
4. A cloud-based web app

Comment: Hi. I believe you asked a similar question in the past, and I gave some solutions to look at. Did you explore "Portfolio Performance"? See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84167/open-source-investment-management-portfolio-tracker-linux-desktop/84170#84170 You are very unlikely to find something of the box. But there are paid professional systems out there.

Comment: @ZZ The other question is similar, but different. This question removes the open-source requirement and specifically asks about tax lots for securities. If you know of paid professional systems, I'd love to hear them :)

Comment: I can't remember from the top of my head. They usually cost a few thousand USD. Did you try out https://www.portfolio-performance.info/en/